# UI Tap Gesture Recognizer Not working does not know which View it was tapped

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 6 different views and I have given them tags as 1,2,3,4,5,6.  I added `UITapGestureRecogniser` from object Library on to the storyboard and made all 6 views  `gestureRecognizers` of it by CTRL+Dragging from views to that `UITapGestureRecogniser`.
 Now in following method I am trying to get tag by tapping different views.

```
 - (IBAction)colorTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        UIView *tappedView= sender.view;
        NSLog(@"%d",tappedView.tag  );

    }
```

but it always shows me the same tag. i.e if i tapped and it was `3` first time, it will be same by tapping other views as well.

Comment: where did you add? Please provide some code.

Comment: I added it from Object library. I actually dropped it on one of the view and then just CTRL+dragged others on to the'Tap Gesture Recogniser' on bottom bar

Comment: You have to use a different gesture recognizer for each view

Comment: so it means if have 30 different custom views i.e Playing Cards, so I need to add separate TapGesture Recogniser for each of them ?

Comment: and What is the purpose of Reference outlet Collections ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each View requires its own Gesture Recognizer set. Here is a piece of code that should work for you.

```
-(void)addTapGesturesToViews
{
    int maxViewTag = 6; // tags must be consective (are in your case)
    for(int i =1; i<= maxViewTag;i++)
    {
        UIView * view = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
        UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(colorTapRecognizer:)];
        tapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGest];
    }

}
```